# change store_id from a template

Tags: products, magento-1.4

We have a template product with a sku of `hcyb` which has product information in the global scope and also for a sample store.  Here is the coding for that part:

```
$temp_prod_id = Mage::getModel( 'catalog/product' )
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter( 'sku', 'hcyb' )
        ->load()->getFirstItem()->getId();

$template = Mage::getModel( 'catalog/product' )
        ->load( $temp_prod_id );

$newProduct = $helper->duplicateProduct($template);
$newProduct->setStoreId($storeId);
```

What that does is create a new series of EAV values so that $storeId is a new record.  What I WANT to do is make it so that the store_id for the template's store scope, when copied over, is changed, not adding the product to another store.

Can someone explain the process involved in this?  Apparently setStoreId is not the way to do this.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Do you want to have two copies of the same product or just change the attribute values for a different storeView? A new product would need a new SKU. Maybe you can add a sample output.

Comment: ok to clarify - the template had one product with attributes (with `store_id` for all those attributes being zero), and one store association with different attributes (some, as needed).  When I duplicate the product I'm duplicating the store_id in the template.  I want to change the `store_id` from say 27701 to 83105, basically hijack all those attributes - if that makes sense.

Comment: So in the end, you want the template to have attributes for ``store_id=0`` and ``store_id=27701`` but the copied product should have attributes for ``store_id=0`` and ``store_id=83105``? that is, remove the store id and add a new one.The new product will be in a different store and should not appear in the same store as the template. Is that correct?

Comment: Maybe you could show the desired output to better understand your situation. Something like a table of the desired values for each store scope. Btw, the line ``$newProduct->setStoreId($storeId);`` only changes the ``store_id`` that will be used to save further changes, but it doesn't do anything on it's own. For example, ``$newProduct->setStoreId($storeId)->setName('New name')->save();`` changes the name of the product for that ``$storeId`` but nothing else. Products aren't "associated" to store views; their attribute values change for each storeview or use the default storeview.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what this `duplicateProduct` method does, but to copy the product, but for a different store_id, you might want to have something like this:

```
/**
 * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $template
 * @param integer $newStoreId
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
 */
public function duplicateProduct($template, $newStoreId = 0)
{
    // Get the data from the template product
    $data = $template->getData();

    // Make sure we don't get the same id
    unset($data['id'], $data['entity_id']);

    $newProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $newProduct->setData($data)
        ->setStoreId($newStoreId)
        ->save();

    return $newProduct;
}
```

Also, the code you posted could be updated as well:

```
$template = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', 'hcyb')
    ->getFirstItem();

$newProduct = $helper->duplicateProduct($template);
```